# Parse Cloud Code multiple push dilemma

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code, before-save

My app has notifications based on zip code and channels.

When a user changes zip code the app updates the `Installation` with the new zip.

In my `beforeSave` on `Installation` I grab the new zip and subscribed channels and search for relevant notifications.

Then I need to send the notifications as pushes back to that installation.

Two questions:

1. Can I just push to the Installation object that came into the `beforeSave` as such:

   `return Parse.Push.send({
       where: request.object
       data: data 
    })`

or do I have to do an Installation query for that objectId?

2. I can't just push the notification object.  I need to configure the data.  If there are multiple notifications (not likely but possible) what's the best way to send multiple pushes back to that installation (assuming I don't want to put them all in one push)?

I can't send the pushes from a `for` loop.  Can I do something like this:

```
return notificationQuery.each().then( function(notification) { 
    //configure push from that notification
    return Parse.Push.send ... etc
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send Push notifications in `parse` based on `channels` or `where`(query) but not both.

So you can do a query on `Installation class` with `channel` and `zipcode`:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('channels', 'Indians');
query.equalTo('zipcode', "345678");

Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  data: {
    action: "com.example.UPDATE_STATUS"
    alert: "Ricky Vaughn was injured in last night's game!",
    name: "Vaughn",
    newsItem: "Man bites dog"
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.   What I meant in the first question is can I just do `{where : request.object}` or even `{where : [request.object]}` since the query is just returning an array of installations and I already have the installation I need.

Comment: If you already have the installations that you need just use the channels in those installations and send a push to the desired ones.

Comment: I have the installation and only need to push to that installation.  Do I have to pass a query to the push or can I pass the installation?  No channels involved.

Comment: See according to the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications-using-channels) you can use either channels or query to send a push. So in your scenario just use a query to `zipcode` to do it.